# Regex to only match first instance

Tags: regex, bash

I've found numerous threads on this, yet somehow I can't seem to find one that addresses something like this specifically:

I want to write a regex that captures 3 consecutive whole words in a paragraph and then stop. Example:

```
I am dog 234 I am cat (@#$#@$#@) I am bear #$F#$F I am frog
```

I only want to capture `I am dog` and nothing more. I'm very close to doing this with `([A-za-z]+\s){3}`, but that will return `I am dogI am catI am bearI am frog`.

How can I modify that regex to only execute **once** and then stop?

Thanks!

Comment: If that pattern is at the start of the string, add `^` at the beginning. Try `^[A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+){2}`.

Comment: So, use `([A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+){2}).*` and grab the capturing group #1 value. Please show your code.

Comment: Please see the comment I just left Muhammad below. Unfortunately I can't assume that the line begins with a word (ie ^[A-Z])

Comment: I do not suggest `^` in my second comment. See https://ideone.com/MDkGic. Try and let me know if the solution works for you.

Comment: That does not seem to work for me, but I can't deny that it works in the script that you wrote. I ran

Comment: ([A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+){2}).* over the text, and it highlights everything after "Invalid"

Comment: I'm using http://www.regexpal.com/ to test these solutions

Comment: Why are you using regexpal.com if you wrote you need it in Bash??? Write it  in your question: it must work at regexpal.com. BUT there is no guarantee it will work in Bash or any other target environment. Never say it does work or does not work just because you tested a regex at a regex testing site. Only test in the target environment.

Comment: So, what is the answer? http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97157?

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with Wictor in this regex issue... If you need to capture the word "I am a dog" from this long string in real world and not in a regex online tester you can try one of these in your bash :

```
$ echo "i am a dog ...." |grep -Po '^([A-Za-z]+\s){3}'

$ echo "i am a dog ...." |perl -pe 's/([A-Za-z].*?)([0-9]).*/\1/'
```

Both will return `I am dog` (tested on Debian 9 with bash 4.4)

Also check this out:

```
$ echo "345 I am dog 234 I am cat (@#$#@$#@) I am bear #$F#$F I am frog" |grep -Po '^.*? \K([A-Za-z]+\s){3}'
I am dog
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use perl I would recommend something like this:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+).*/$1 $2 $3/'
```

The `.*?` at the start is a non greedy match so if your string starts with 3 words it will match nothing but if not it will match everything until the start of three words.

Answer (score -1):

I could not solve this purely via regex, but was able to figure out a solution in Bash which was to do

grep -Po '((?:[A-Za-z]+\s){3})' | head -n 1

This puts each match on its own line and then prints the first line.

Thanks everyone for your help, I'm sorry if my wording was confusing.